# UICollectionView change Drop Placeholder index path

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop

I would like to implement the following UX using Drag & Drop. Brief: the user should be able to insert an item only at the end.

1. User may drag an item from whatever source and point it on a Collection View.
2. When the item hangs above the view, the placeholder appears in the specific position, e.g. at the end.
3. When user releases the item, it animates to the placeholder's index.

[image: Drag & Drop UX example - inserting at the end]

I can implement the step 3 adopting the [`UICollectionViewDropDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdropdelegate):

```
func collectionView(
    _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {

    // ...
    coordinator.drop(item, toItemAt: endIndexPath)
}
```

**The problem is to change the placeholder index**, which is under the drag item by default. We could use [`collectionView(_:dropSessionDidUpdate:withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdropdelegate/2897375-collectionview) to provide a proposal. But there is no variable to specify index path in [`UICollectionViewDropProposal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdropproposal).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `collectionView(_:targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt:toProposedIndexPath:)`. While it's not the last index, return originalIndexPath.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt originalIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {        
    guard proposedIndexPath.item == lastItemIndex // Here should be some logic to calculate the last index
        else { return originalIndexPath }
    return proposedIndexPath
}
```

**However, for some implementations, this function never gets called**. For example, when you use a UICollectionViewController. In this case, return **.cancel** proposal on drop — `UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)` in the `collectionView(_:dropSessionDidUpdate:withDestinationIndexPath:)` function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
  dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession,
  withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?)
  -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {

    guard destinationIndexPath?.item != lastItemIndex // Here should be some logic to calculate the last index
    else {
        return UICollectionViewDropProposal(
         operation: .cancel,
         intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
    }
  return UICollectionViewDropProposal(
    operation: .move,
    intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
}
```

Comment: I'll test your answer later and give some meaningful feedback.